# Defragment Drives (dfrgui.exe) won't start after 1703 Update

Tags: windows-10, debug

All, this is a curious problem after the creators (1703) update (OS Build 15063.413) on my HP Elitebook 8760w. `Defragment and Optimize drives` will not launch at all. For instance clicking on `Start menu -> Microsoft Administrative Tools -> Defragment and Optimize Drives` does nothing. With task manager open, it is apparent that no process has started. (or doesn't run enough to register) Further, opening an administrator console and executing `dfrgui.exe` does nothing either.

I'm hoping someone here may have a few thoughts on how to further debug the issue. From the kernel trace performed below, attempting to launch `dfrgui.exe` results in an *ExitStatus 259* and actual *ErrorCode 15005* apparently pointing to event data not matching template provided in manifest?? Defragment and Optimize drives worked just fine yesterday morning before the update, now nothing.

I've updated to KB4022716 (OS Build 15063.447) from the update catalog -- no help (it did fix a lot of other issues in the first version .413 update).

Here are a couple of diagnostic on what I get from the command line, dfrgui -- nothing, defrag -- OK:

```
PS C:\Users\david> dfrgui
PS C:\Users\david> write-host $?
True

PS C:\Users\david> dfrgui /?
PS C:\Users\david> dfrgui c:


PS C:\Users\david> defrag /?
 Microsoft Drive Optimizer
 Copyright (c) 2013 Microsoft Corp.

Description:

        Optimizes and defragments files on local volumes to
         improve system performance.

<snip>
```

In further effort to run the problem down, I created a kernel trace of the attempt to start dfrgui.exe with a short batch file:

```
logman start "NT Kernel Logger" -p "Windows Kernel Trace" (process,thread,img,disk,net,registry) -o systemevents.etl -ets
dfrgui.exe
logman stop "NT Kernel Logger" -ets
```

I then processed the event file, *systemevents.etl*, (5.5M) with `tracerpt systemevents.etl` which created a huge 46M `dumpfile.xml`. I have reviewed the dumpfile and paired it down to the starting and ending events related to `dfrgui.exe` (which thankfully is only 428K). However, I'm no wizard in interpreting window kernel tracing. Both files are too large to use here, but I can make further parts available if they will help.

The one set of event data that stood out was:

```
 <EventData>
   <Data Name="UniqueProcessKey">0xFFFFA008A692A2C0</Data>
   <Data Name="ProcessId">0xFCC</Data>
   <Data Name="ParentId">0x25F8</Data>
   <Data Name="SessionId">       1</Data>
   <Data Name="ExitStatus">259</Data>
   <Data Name="DirectoryTableBase">0x1EAF8A000</Data>
   <Data Name="Flags">       0</Data>
   <Data Name="UserSID">\\ELITE\david</Data>
   <Data Name="ImageFileName">dfrgui.exe</Data>
   <Data Name="CommandLine">dfrgui.exe</Data>
   <Data Name="PackageFullName"></Data>
   <Data Name="ApplicationId"></Data>
  </EventData>
```

Looking, the next event is important as it relates to processing the error:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
   <Provider Guid="{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}" />
   <EventID>0</EventID>
   <Version>3</Version>
   <Level>0</Level>
   <Task>0</Task>
   <Opcode>1</Opcode>
   <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
   <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-07-02T00:16:57.024179100-0500" />
   <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
   <Execution ProcessID="9720" ThreadID="11156" ProcessorID="2" KernelTime="45" UserTime="15" />
   <Channel />
   <Computer />
  </System>
  <ProcessingErrorData>
   <ErrorCode>15005</ErrorCode>
   <DataItemName />
   <EventPayload>CC0F0000082800000040659081D9FFFF00E0649081D9FFFF0000C8987A00000000E0C7987A0000000F000000000000008020DDE7F77F000000B0B8987A00000000000000080502000000</EventPayload>
  </ProcessingErrorData>
  <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
   <Opcode>Start</Opcode>
   <Provider>MSNT_SystemTrace</Provider>
   <EventName xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">Thread</EventName>
  </RenderingInfo>
  <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
   <EventGuid>{3d6fa8d1-fe05-11d0-9dda-00c04fd7ba7c}</EventGuid>
  </ExtendedTracingInfo>
 </Event>
```

The `15005` error code being:

```
ERROR_EVT_INVALID_EVENT_DATA
  15005 (0x3A9D)
  The event data raised by the publisher is not compatible 
  with the event template definition in the publisher's manifest.
```

(according to:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384(v=vs.85).aspx)

I suspect the answer is buried in the long string of bytes contained in the   I posted as part of the kernel trace. (which is something I have no idea how to decode).

I do find the ExitStatus 259 a bit ironic given:

> "Important  The GetExitCodeProcess function returns a valid error code
>   defined by the application only after the thread terminates.
>   Therefore, an application should not use STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an
>   error code. If a thread returns  STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code,
>   applications that test for this value could interpret it to mean that
>   the thread is still running and continue to test for the completion of
>   the thread after the thread has terminated, which could put the
>   application into an infinite loop."

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Does anyone have any further ideas regarding what I can try to get dfrgui.exe running? If not, are there any other diagnostics I could do? I've posted to the microsoft answers board, but so far, I have only received a "Me Too" for the issue and suggestions to roll back. (which since this seems the only problem I know of, hardly makes the risk of a rollback attractive). What to try next? Let me know if there is something else I can post that might help.

---

On the suggestion of Biswa, after tracking down further option descriptions for `defrag.exe` to insure operations were correct for my SSD, I attempted a manual trim with it. It appears `dfrag.exe` is doing nothing as well other than starting and then exiting without more. Example,

```
PS C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\gtk\gtkwrite> defrag /C /H /O /V
Microsoft Drive Optimizer
Copyright (c) 2013 Microsoft Corp.

PS C:\Users\david\Documents\dev\gtk\gtkwrite> write-host $?
True
```

So it appears `defrag` is doing nothing but printing the copyright and exiting. I have also tried with simply `C: /A /V` to get it to analyze `C` specifically, but no matter what I try, it simply prints the copyright and exits.

I have run another kernel trace on defrag.exe and the output is virtually identical to dfrgui.exe. Same 259 ExitStatus. The EventPayload in the event following the defrag.exe ExitStatus was:

```
<EventPayload>B4090000EC2B000000C0430081D6FFFF0060430081D6FFFF00003802BC00000000E03702BC0000000F0000000000000060B0E1B7F77F000000B04102BC00000000000000080502000000</EventPayload>
```

Comment: See if "Optimize drives" service is in manual state and running. Try to defragment C drive with `defrag C: /U /V` command.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm a bit leery of running `defrag` itself on the drive since it is an SSD. `dfrgui.exe` automatically handled `trim` instead. It's unclear, but it looks like the `/L` option would `retrim` if that is the proper operation here. `/O` also seems like a candidate to perform the proper operation for each media type. I'll do a bit more digging and post the results. `dfrag` itself is working fine, it's just `dfrgui.exe` that is on the fritz.

Answer (score 1):

**Ahah! I found the problem!**

For some reason unexplained (perhaps a cosmic string was tweaked wrong on 1703 install, or just gremlins) the `"Optimize drives"` service startup was `"Disabled"`. Don't ask me how or why...

Basically snooping though `TaskMgr` services led me to `'defragsvc'` which I then rt-clicked to `"open in Services"`. I then found 'defragsvc' was actually renamed `"Optimize drives"`. Checking properties, I found it **disabled** (which I changed to `'Manual'`) and viola! Clicking on **Defragment and Optimize Drives** in the start menu now works as it should.

4 days of headache over a darn app that won't tell you *"Hey I'm based on a Disabled Service"* when you invoke it from the command line....

Now the question to the MS devs is *"what the heck caused this to be set to disabled during 1703 update??*" It was not disabled before the 1703 update took place.